# How to make headless Ubuntu server play consistent 'beep' when boot process is ready and waiting to enter luks key

Tags: boot, sound, luks

I was wondering how is possible to make a headless Ubuntu server to play a consistent beeping sound when boot process is ready and waiting user to unlock hdd with luks key; Like an alarm or so "hey Iam ready, you can type the key now"

Comment: https://www.iavit.org/~john/debian/grub.html - This might be able to do what you want it to. GRUB has a variable to enable playing a beep.

Comment: It's not answering the question this link. Have to beep when is ready to accept luks key from users keyboard. Beep should be consistent annoying.